# How can I add property-like behavior to a instance of a class?

Tags: python, properties, python-2.x

I need to "highjack" access to a member of a object instance without modifying the behavior of all instances of that class.  Is this achievable?

Consider the following stripped down code:

```
class S(object):
    pass

Class C(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.r = -1
        self.s = s
        # Add missing bits here?

s = S()    
c = C(s)
print c.s.r # => should return the value of c.r, i.e. -1
c.s.r = -2  # should modify the value of c.r
s.r = -3    # ditto, should modify the value of c.r
```

Note that a given instance of `S` may be used in isolation as well as being shared between multiple `C` objects so setting a property on `S.__class__` doesn't work (or at least not in any incarnation I've managed to come up with so far).

Any ideas?

Comment: If `c.s` is an `S` instance, why would `c.s.r` mean the `r` attribute of `C` instance rather than the `r` attribute of the `S` instance?

Comment: That's the issue at hand; when an S instance is used in isolation, i.e. hasn't been passed to a C instance, s.r should mean the r attribute of s, but here I'm trying to 'highjack' it once inside a C instance.  As for the why, in RL both classes have methods decorators which modify the 'r' attribute when certain calls are made on the objects. So, they could at any point both have a value set on 'r', but only the latest modification is logically valid and trying to figure out how to redirect that access at runtime.

Comment: I don't think you could do this without modifying class `S`. Also, what `C` instance would something like `s.r` refer to (i.e. how could an `S` instance know what `C` instance to access to retrieve the value of the  `r` attribute from)?

Comment: Does S have other attributes which should be reachable if accessed via C, or do you want to intercept all calls to `c.s.x` and replace with `c.x`?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of making C::__init__ assign some kind of a proxy object to s.r, but hadn't figured out how to not have a `s.r = X` overwrite that object. Next idea was to look into the decorator pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) but decided to post here first to see if anyone else had a better idea...

Answer (score 0):

```
class S(object):
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.r = r

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

s = S(-1)    
c = C(s)
print(c.s.r)
c.s.r = -2 

print(c.s.r)
print(s.r)

s.r = -3 

print(c.s.r)
print(s.r)
```

Comment: if you want to access "r" via "s", i.e. via "s.r", then "r" must be an attribute on "s". If you want to also access this via "c", then "s" must be an attribute on "c". If you want to edit "r" in "c" without doing so in "s" you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

figure I'd post what I ended up with:

```
import weakref

class S(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._r = -1

    @property
    def r(self):
        try:
            return self._c.r
        except (AttributeError, ReferenceError):
            return self._r

    @r.setter
    def r(self, value):
        try:
            self._c.r = value
        except (AttributeError, ReferenceError):
            self._r = value


class C(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self._r = -2
        s._c = weakref.proxy(self)
        self.s = s

    @property
    def r(self):
        return self._r

    @r.setter
    def r(self, value):
        self._r = value

def printRs(s, c):
    print "s.r", s.r
    if c:
        print "c.r", c.r
        print "c.s.r", c.s.r

s = S()
c = C(s)
printRs(s, c)  # => -2 on all
c.r = 0
printRs(s, c)  # => 0 on all
s.r = 1
printRs(s, c)  # => 1 on all
c.s.r = 2
printRs(s, c)  # => 2 on all
c = None
printRs(s, c)  # => -1 on s.r
```